# improving a heavily used LCD's screen life, some questions

Tags: display, lcd, lifespan

I have a 24 inch LCD and the LCD display of my laptop which are extensively used, so i cannot save the screen by keeping it turned (using less). I have already set the display options to shut down the LCD after 1 minute (so screensaver is irrelevant) but still that shut down doesn't happen very often.

My laptop screen has already started to lose colors (colors have become less rich and more grayish, white has become yellowish), but it has been more than two years but i started to see fading after almost 1 year, which i do not want to see happening so soon to the new screen and the new laptop.

My questions are:

1. How can i prevent the colors from dimming as long as possible?
2. What is generally the life of LCD, i mean before one should start seeing the effects of an old display?
3. Does LED last longer? Should i chose LED instead? Is there any other better alternative (except CRT)?
4. Setting the display to turn off, it frequently happens that I have to turn it back on at the same moment, does it cause problems? And in this case is a screensaver equally good alternative?
5. What about temperatures? Summers are around 45 C, are precautions needed? Both for LCD and LED?

Thanks

Comment: I have a 12 year old laptop that i converted into a picture frame that runs 24/7 - no fade'ing is noticable on it.. Then i have several other  notebooks i use daily.. Acer.. i notice its not so bright any more.. Dell.. no problems.. HP-very good but some cable problem from using to much.. Its only depends on the quality of the screen.. Turning it ON and OFF too much can damage it more than leaving it on! MOst of my computer run 24/7 .. just because 1 is not enough for me anymore...And i dont use screensaver.. but i dim/turn off dispaly after 1 hour.. because i am sleeping..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use as low as possible brightness, (it is better for your eyes anyway,) avoid exposure to sun, avoid high temperatures. (Yes, 45°C is kind of hot.) I do not know about LED.

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine Turning somewhat yellowish, is from the Phosphors wearing out on the tube.  I am assuming this is probably a CCT backlight. you could just replace the tube, because the circuit that drives the tube is not bad, replacement is easier (i wont say easy) .  turning down the backlight brightness, preserves the phosphors.  When it comes to LED vrses CCT , it would depend 100% on the quality of each. and the color changes on LED would be different. turning on/off LED has zero effect, on the leds themselves, they love it, only the curcuit would be bothered if at all.

Comment: screensavers are a waste on anything other than CRTs, they are cute and fun, and DO work to a tiny degree on LCD pannels (really old tech ones), but unlike CRT the modern stuff is better with a screen off than a screen saver.  LEDs need to be properly cooled, in the temps your discussing, added to the temps inside the computer, and the lack of active cooling for them, it would be worse than CCTs. again especially if the design and quality of the leds is cheap.